# Websockets in WebViews failing to connect, returning code 1006

Tags: android, websocket, webview

I have created a simple websocket in an HTML page that works great and connects fine in all of the web browsers. However, when I load it in a web view like in an Android App it fails to connect and returns the code 1006.  It is trying to connect to a different URL/endpoint so I am thinking this might be a CORS issue. I am building for a minimum target of API 23.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Socket Connect</h1>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
<script>
    const div = document.getElementById('container');

    try {
        console.log('connect');
        var ws = new WebSocket('wss://anotherserver.com:3000');
        ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
    }
    catch (err) {

    }
    ws.onerror = function (error) {
        // error is always blank
        console.log('error');
    };
    ws.onopen = function () {
        div.textContent = 'Opened';
        console.log('opened');
    };
     ws.onclose = function (error) {
        //  always = 1006
        div.textContent = error.code;
        console.log(error.code);
    };
    
    </script>

</html>
```

I have read a few other posts about setting some options in my code and I have done that. See here

```
    myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(currentCacheMode); /* use cache if not expired */
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

I have set cleartext in my manifest as well

Comment: What does 1006 mean?

Comment: In all webbrowsers? Also in a webbrowser from an Android device?

Comment: I spoke too soon. I can reproduce it in firefox. Fails in Chrome on iOS and Android. Fails in firefox.    It works in safari in iOS, OSX and it works in chrome in osx as well.

Comment: Yes it was a CORS issue with same origin

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a CORS issue.